# Markov random field and iterated condition mode

Tags: markov-process, image-processing

I have spent a lot of time studying MRF (applied to images) but still can't grasp the idea. Could you please clarify these ideas:

1. What is the clique potential? What is a clique in image, and do they overlap?
2. In ICM, people do MAP estimation. As far as I know, posterior is P(parameter| data), so what are parameters here?
3. They also applied Gibbs sampling in estimation. What probability distribution are they sampling? And why you need to do sampling?